# Xcode 5 upgraded , stuck at Xcode 4.6.3

Tags: mac-appstore, xcode

I upgraded my Xcode 4.6.3 to Xcode 5 on app store but when the upgraded is finish and open my Xcode it is still Xcode 4.6.3, it should be Xcode 5? What is the problem here.

Comment: Do you use the XCode in /Applications and not the XCode in /Developer/Applications?
Your Mac OS X version is at least Mountain Lion up-to-date ?

Answer (score 1):

Found at /Developer, I found a way to uninstall Xcode via

```
$ sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

I just ran the installer for Xcode 4, and it detected old version of Xcode, offering me to move it to /Developer-old.